# Entity Framework 6.4 supports Second level (L2) result caching?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-4.6, entity-framework-6.4

I would like to know whether EF 6.4 supports second revel caching (result caching - not query caching) without extending with a third-party library like EntityFramework.Cache or NCache.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/35549009/entity-framework-second-level-cache), even on the official entity framework site, there is mention of only third party libraries.

The most recent [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/september/data-points-second-level-caching-in-the-entity-framework-and-appfabric) (I could find) on the subject is back on 2011

> The EF doesn’t have built-in support for working with second-level caches. That functionality would make the most sense as part of the ObjectContext and DbContext logic when they’re about to interact with the database. But implementing the caching while taking into account the various issues discussed in the ACM article is non-trivial, especially with the lack of obvious extensibility points in the EF. One of the features that’s frequently highlighted as a big difference between the EF and NHibernate is the fact that NHibernate has built-in support for implementing second-level caching.